# How can I show the error messages that may appear at startup?

Tags: error

I am getting an error message about my terminal setting when I start Vim, but it just appears on the screen for a second, so it is hard to read.

I tried `:messages` but it is not shown.

How can get access to the message text?

Comment: If it’s not shown by `:messages`, than it’s not using `:echom`—and it’s going to be harder. Things I would try off the top of my head: use `:debug` from a `--cmd` switch, or the verbose flag, or (i think) some sort of logfile option.

Comment: You can try running Vim under `script`, which should catch all and any terminal output...

Comment: Where exactly are the errors showing up? In the status bar? If all else fails, you could record your desktop...

Comment: @StefanSchroeder The error appears in the middle of the screen.